# Explanation and proper format of "parameterTypes" in "java.lang.Class.getMethod()" method

Tags: java, reflection, format, parameter-passing, inner-classes

I have the following code -

`MyInterface.java` -

```
    default int getNumber() {
        System.out.print("Number: ");
        return in.nextInt();
    }

    default void displayNumber(int num) {
        System.out.println("Number: " + num);
    }
```

`Main.java` -

```
        int num;

        MyInterface obj = new MyInterface() {
        };

        num = (int) obj.getClass().getMethod("getNumber").invoke(obj);
        obj.getClass().getMethod("displayNumber", parameterType).invoke(obj);
```

I have left out the `exceptions` for clarity purpose

Here I have created the `interface` - `MyInterface` with two `methods` -

One `method` reads a number and returns it.

The other `method` takes a number as `parameter` and prints it.

In `Main` `method` I have created an `inner class` to implement the `interface`

Now using `reflection`  and `getMethod()` I am able to successfully call the first `method` to read a number.

But I don't know the proper format to pass an `argument` using `getMethod()` and hence I am unable to successfully call the second `method`.

Here, what should be in place of `parameterType`?

Comment: Tried `getMethod("displayNumber", int.class)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While ajc2000's answer is correct, I'd like to point out that the .class syntax would also work:

[Retrieving Class Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html)

> If the type is available but there is no instance then it is possible
>   to obtain a Class by appending ".class" to the name of the type. This
>   is also the easiest way to obtain the Class for a primitive type.

That is, the following would also work:

```
obj.getClass().getMethod("displayNumber", int.class).invoke(obj, 5);
```

Comment: Ah, so it turns out that autoboxing still does occur!  This works too (with regard to the parameter being 5 rather than new Integer(5))

Answer (score 2):

In Java Reflection, we represent types with `Class` objects.  For any primitive, this can be obtained with the `.TYPE` value from any primitive wrapper class.  In your instance, it looks like this would be `Integer.TYPE` (this would be the value for `parameterType`).

Note also when you actually invoke `displayNumber` you will need to supply some actual value for your argument.  For example, to represent the method invocation `displayNumber(5)`, you would have to make the last line the following:

`obj.getClass().getMethod("displayNumber", Integer.TYPE).invoke(obj, new Integer(5));`

As you can see, I am being careful with not assuming that primitive 5 is being autoboxed, as we tend to use `Object` as the static type frequently in Java reflection.

Comment: Also "new Integer(5)" gives me the warning in Eclipse - "The constructor Integer(int) is deprecated since version 9"

Comment: @acidic_base since Java 5, you should use `Integer.valueOf(5)` instead of `new Integer(5)`. This is what auto-boxing does for you automatically.

Comment: @Holger Ok but ajc2000 still didn't answer what I have to put in place of "parameterType". Is it "int.class" ?

Comment: @Holger Also if this is from Java 5, then why eclipse is showing me the warning that it is depreciated from Java 9 instead?

Comment: @acidic_base This answer says that `Integer.TYPE` would be the right value for `parameterType`, which is ok, as it evaluates to exactly the same `Class` object as using `int.class` like in the accepted answer. Since Java 5, you can use `Integer.valueOf(...)` which is also what auto-boxing uses, which was introduced in the same version. Since then, using `Integer.valueOf(...)` or just auto-boxing, is the preferred way to get an `Integer` instance, but the constructor has not been marked as `@Deprecated` until Java 9.

Comment: @acidic_base sorry I wasn't clear, edited by answer - `Integer.TYPE` is the value of `parameterType`

Comment: And yeah I learned much of Java during Java 7/8, so I am only learning today that the `Integer(int)` constructor is deprecated